# How to Apply global font to whole HTML document

Tags: html, css, font-family

I have a HTML page which includes some text and formatting. I want to make it have the same font-family and the same text-size ignoring all inner formatting of text.

I want to set a global font format for the HTML page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 338, accepted):

You should be able to utilize the asterisk and `!important` elements within CSS.

```
html *
{
   font-size: 1em !important;
   color: #000 !important;
   font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

The asterisk matches everything (you could probably get away without the `html` too).

The `!important` ensures that **nothing can override what you've set in this style** (unless it is also important). (this is to help with your requirement that it should "ignore inner formatting of text" - which I took to mean that other styles could not overwrite these)

The rest of the style within the braces is just like any other styling and you can do whatever you'd like to in there. I chose to change the font size, color and family as an example.

Comment: +1 `!important` is useful, but it can get a bit "thar be monsters" if it gets overused.

Comment: +1 for providing a great use of `!important`. It must always be used as last option.

Comment: Note the use of `!important` here is due to the original poster's requirement, "have the same font-family and the same text-size ignoring all inner formatting of text." If you don't have that requirement, you don't want to use `!important`.

Comment: Use of `html * {}` or `body * {}` will help you to avoid override through more specific `body p {}` in included style sheets. `body p {}` is more specific than `body {}`, so the asterisk is an important element here.

Comment: I think you can omit `html` from `html *` here

Comment: NOTE: if ur using `<i>`-based icons, such as Google Icons, you're gonna have to add `.material-icons{
     font-family: 'Material Icons' !important;
}`

Comment: This will break icon fonts like Fontawesome though. <i class="fa fa-circle"></i> will stop working.

Answer (score 60):

Best practice I think is to set the font to the body:

```
body {
    font: normal 10px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

and if you decide to change it for some element it could be easily overwrited:

```
h2, h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: if you are using a framework like foundation css this does not work without adding !important.

Comment: I agree, and think the accepted answer is an abomination, although I accept that it answers the actual question of 'ignoring all inner formatting'. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68249715/2652785) on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925682/where-to-set-font-family-body-or-html-element) as to *why* setting font properties on `body` is best practice.

Answer (score 17):

Set it in the body selector of your css. E.g.

```
body {
    font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This can be overridden with more specific selectors.

Comment: It wouldn't apply to all element, for example: input type='button'

Answer (score 15):

Use the following css:

```
* {
    font: Verdana, Arial, 'sans-serif' !important;/* <-- fonts */
}
```

The `*`-selector means **any/all** elements, but will obviously be on the bottom of the food chain when it comes to overriding more *specific* selectors.

Note that the `!important`-flag will render the `font`-style for `*` to be absolute, even if other selectors have been used to set the text (for example, the `body` or maybe a `p`).

Comment: Maybe `!important` would prevent other selectors from overriding the settings.

Comment: Well, yes, `!important` would prevent other selectors from overriding, as long as they don't also use it. Heh. I'll edit my post and add it - thanks. :-)

Comment: Yep, that's right. Not quite sure, but I think the preference also depends on where you place the declaration. If you place it at the very bottom, I may also override the `!important`s from the more specific selectors above. But that's not quite the point here I guess :)

Comment: This is the only answer that actually worked for me. Not sure why, but it did.

Comment: It only works for me if I use "font-family:", not "font:"

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
body
{
    font-family:your font;
    font-size:your value;
    font-weight:your value;
}
```

Comment: Hi anglimass, I formatted your code, if you use 4 spaces or the `{}` button you can display example code in this way in your answers.