# Polish signs in shinydashboard

Tags: r, utf-8, shiny, shinydashboard

I've got problem with polish signs in `shinydashboard`. When I'm using just `shiny` everything is ok, but in `shinydashboard` `ą` and `ę` are written in different font. I've tried to change encoding of a document, but it didn't help. I don't really know how to deal with it... Could you help me?

My code:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(h1("przejścią"))
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And visualisation of my problem:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried open in google chrome? Sometimes the rstudio builtin browser is not that good to render fonts and images.

Comment: @jbkunst, yes, I've tried and it still doesn't work...

Comment: You can try to manipulate with locale https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html. For me setting locale to "Polish" helped.

Comment: @zuku, I've added `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Polish")` and `Sys.setenv(LANG = "POLISH_POLAND.UTF-8")`, but it didn't help.

Comment: It's probably due to the font used by `shinydashboard` (Source Sans Pro), you could try with another font: `dashboardBody(tags$style(HTML("h1 {font-family: Arial;}")),h1("przejścią"))`

Comment: @NicE, thanks! It really works. Do you know how to change font in the whole dashboard, not only in the `h1` header?

Comment: Maybe have a look here https://github.com/vnijs/radiant/issues/25

Comment: These [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041706/applying-a-single-font-to-an-entire-website-with-css) should work to set the font for the whole website.