# Apply CSS rule to all elements except one with it's children

Tags: css, angular

I have this CSS rule:

```
* {
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

I want to apply the rule to all elements except this `div`, which is unique by class, and it's children:

```
<div class="angular-text-editor">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

font-family for this div and it's children should be picked by the user, but now because of the * rule applied, the new selected font can not be applied to them, even with !important.

I want some css rule which ensures that the * rule will apply to all elements except this div and it's children.

I even tried using the `:not` selector, but it was not helpful with the children.

thanks

Comment: It would likely be cleaner, and more clear if you were to write a CSS rule targeting that `div` and it's content overriding the global style.

Comment: if you mean the **!important**, i've tried that too, i want the font-family to be unset at all, but with the override it gets the font from * again.

Answer (score 2):

Select the unique `div` with it's descendants and assign them a different `font-family`

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.a, .a * {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
   first text
   <p>more text</p>
   <div>
      further nested text
      <p>more text</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   second text
   <p>more text</p>
</div>
```

Or assign `font-family` to `body` tag and use `unset` on unique element, `inherit` on it's descendants.

```css
.a {
  font-family: unset;
}

.a * {
  font-family: inherit !important;
}

body *:not(.a) {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
   first text
   <p>more text</p>
   <div>
      further nested text
      <p>more text</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   second text
   <p>more text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it was very smart.
but i am dynamically setting the font for that class, and i need it to be unset. but i see that * thing is applying to them. 
your code works correctly for an assigned font, but with unset it was not working.

Comment: If you are already setting the font where is the problem? Please edit your question to include all relevant information. If you are using `*` selector it also affects your `body` tag. Therefore if you unset the font on `div.a` it will inherit a font from `body`.

Comment: Added an alternative that uses `unset`, but the end result is basically the same.

Comment: the :not you used for body will affect only the div and it won't work for it's children.

Comment: It seems your problem might not be with CSS, if you look at my second example you can either set `font-family` on `body` or `.a` and it does override `*:not()` selector.

Comment: thanks anyway, it solved some of it, really helpful.

Comment: There might be some confusion as to what `unset` does. `unset` sets an inherited property (which `font-family` is) of an element to the same as its parent - which seems to be the opposite of what you are trying to do.

Comment: you are right, that's the problem i want the css rule for font to be added to all but this div and it's children, and i used the id or class, it is a little complex with **not** selector and it can not be applied. @SwimmerF
even the unset makes my fonts unavalible as you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

i changed the css rule to this :

```
body {
 font-family: Tahoma !important;
}
```

so all elements will inherit it if they don't have their own...
special thanks to this man :

[Applying a single font to an entire website with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041706/applying-a-single-font-to-an-entire-website-with-css/10041724)