# How to change font normal to Foundry Sterling Bold?

Tags: css, font-face

I want to change my font it will be Foundry Sterling bold.

How to do that? Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <style> 
            @font-face { 
                font-family: Foundry Sterling Bold;; 
                src: url('FoundrySterling-Bold.ttf'); 
            }
            p { 
                font-family:"Foundry Sterling Bold"; 
            } 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="fsb">Bangalore</p>
        <p>Bangalore</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Apply global font to whole HTML document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025756/how-to-apply-global-font-to-whole-html-document)

Answer (score 0):

```
selector {
    font-family: "Foundry Sterling Bold";
}
```

Comment: What is your selector? Is it an element? The whole page?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<style>
p{
font-family:"Foundry Sterling Bold";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Bangalore</p>
<p>Bangalore</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Sanjeevkumar The code is correct. The reason it doesn't display is probably because the client browser does not have this font installed. Consider choosing a "web safe" font, this seems like quite an obscure font to me, and it makes sense that your browser doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the font?

If so, try this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myfontname;
    src: url(public_html/mywebsite/fonts/myfont.woff);
}

p {
 font-family: "myfontname";
}
```

Comment: /* here is my code it's not working please explain with example */                 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: Foundry Sterling Bold;;
    src: url('FoundrySterling-Bold.ttf');
}

p {
 font-family:"Foundry Sterling Bold";
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="fsb">Bangalore</p>
<p>Bangalore</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You have to be more specific with the url('') where is it stored? For instance when i'm using a custom font, I'm uploading it through a FTP client to a directory where all my fonts are. I gave you an example above, so you should try this. Otherwise you have two semicolons after Foundry Sterling Bold;; - you only need one ;)