# Where to set font-family: body or html element?

Tags: html, css

Where is it best to declare the `font-family` CSS property? On the `html` or `body` element?

```
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

or

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

I searched online, but I cant find a definitive answer.

Comment: I would suggest to make a css class property and apply it there. using 
`<style>
body{
font-family:'property'
}
</style>`

Comment: font-family is a CSS property, so it belongs neither to the html nor the body tag.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739601/what-is-the-difference-between-applying-css-rules-to-html-compared-to-body and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187569/whats-the-difference-in-applying-css-to-html-body-and for clarification.

Comment: If you are using `rem` units, make sure to set the base font size on the `html` element. `rem` units are based off the font size of the root element, which is the `html` element.

Answer (score 26):

The short answer is, you can use either. Since every displayed element is a descendant of the `body` element, and the `body` element itself is the child of the `html` element, all elements that inherit the `font-family` property will happily adopt it from either. (If a particular element doesn't inherit it, you can always override its `font-family` property with a value of `inherit`.)

But what is best practice, and why? That's a bit harder to answer, but I'll have a go. Let's start with semantics…

The [`html` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element) represents the whole *document* (including non-visible metadata), while the [`body` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element) represents the *content* of the document. Since `font-family` is a property of styled *content*, it would seem logical to apply it to `body`. That's one point for `body`.

Next question: Where do the browsers define text formatting properties like `font-family`? I looked at the user agent stylesheets for [Safari (WebKit)](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css), [Mozilla Firefox](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/html.css) and [Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/main/Source/core/css/html.css), and also used the Web Inspector on a page with no overriding CSS, but I couldn't find a global `font-family` declaration anywhere. But here's something interesting… In Safari, the global text `color` property is defined on the `html` element. So, if that's anything to go by, it suggests WebKit browsers do define global font properties on the `html` element.

There are CSS resets that also tackle it here, like Bootstrap's `_reboot.scss` file:

```css
// 2. Change the default font family in all browsers.
html {
   font-family: sans-serif; // 2
   …
}
```

Still, we can override this on the `body` element, and that is just what Bootstrap does a few lines later:

```css
body {
   margin: 0; // 1
   font-family: $font-family-base;
   …
}
```

Half a point to `html`?

The CSS specs (as far as I know) don't dictate where `font-family` is declared (it applies to 'all elements'), but it does give us some hints. The first code example in the W3C document [CSS Fonts Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/) is this:

```css
body {
   font-family: Helvetica;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Another one is [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/):

```css
body {
   font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
   font-size: 12pt;
   margin: 3em;
}
```

It explains:

> The first declaration on the BODY element sets the font family to "Gill Sans". If that font is not available, the user agent (often referred to as a "browser") will use the [sans-serif](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#valdef-generic-family-sans-serif) font family which is one of five generic font families which all users agents know. Child elements of BODY will inherit the value of the [font-family](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#propdef-font-family) property.

Another point to `body`.

Final scores:

`body`: 2
`html`: 0.5

Winner: `body`! :-D

Answer (score 10):

Best practice is to set the `font-family` in the `body`.

```
body {
   font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

The `!important` is useful here so that in case you are using any other framework, your `font-family` does not get overridden.

You can also use the `*` selector.

```
* {
    font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

The `*`-selector means any/all elements, but will obviously be on the bottom of the property chain when it comes to overriding more specific selectors.

Note that the `!important` flag will render the font-style for `*` to be absolute, even if other selectors have been used to set the text (for example, the `body` or maybe a `p`).

Comment: You say to set it in the body yet your example sets it for `<html>`

Comment: Any reason as to why this is best practice? Care to expand or add a source?

Comment: People are way too trigger happy with the universal selector (*) IMO. It's an inefficient selector that literally selects Every. Single. Element. (The cascade exists to avoid this sort of thing.) Stamping it with `!important` is heaping sin upon sin.

Answer (score 5):

The `*` selector will give you better coverage. For example, `form` elements, like `input`, don't inherit font styles from `html` and `body` tags. But if you set it with `*` then you'll make sure your font styles pass down to all HTML elements.

```
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Here's a demo. Using [* selector](http://jsfiddle.net/VolkerShmuley/gpkzhec4/2/) vs [html and body](http://jsfiddle.net/VolkerShmuley/1t7fg20x/2/).

Comment: This is precisely the reason why I believe this method is best. I guess the question now is will it overwrite even the font family of embeds with iframes?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add styles to `<body>` tag. Because it contains hierarchy, so it follows that it must contain all global styles.

Refer: https://css-tricks.com/html-vs-body-in-css/

Comment: Your explanation for using `<body>` makes no sense. What does 'it contains hierarchy' even mean? The CSS-Tricks article is a good read though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the project the best place would be a separately linked style page that contains all your css code. But from your question it sounds as if you want to write it into your HTML.

And if you want to do it in the same file as your HTML, than an internal style sheet is the 2nd best choice, and place "style"  tags within your "head" tags and write your CSS within the "style tags.

```
<head>
  <style>
    <!–– Insert CSS Code Here -->
  </style>
</head>
```

Otherwise you just write it inline (at the point of the element you are trying to style).

Now what method is best depends on the project but it is generally thought that an external style sheet is the first option as it makes it easy for someone else to follow along with which elements are affected by what styling. If it's a small project with not much CSS than an "Internal Style Sheet is the next best option, again for readability and keeping your CSS in one place. Inline styling although possible is not really encouraged.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have updated my question as it was unclear what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you will have one font family on website, the best way to do that is to use

`*` selector, this one select all elements so:

```
*{
   font-family:"your-font-family";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the font-family of the entire page I would have to agree with user7357089 and nashcheez  that the "best" method would be to place it in the body tag. All of your visible HTML would be contained within the body tag anyway, adding it to the HTML would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it would probably make sense to specify the `font-family` on the `body`. However, since there isn't exactly very many downsides to applying it to the `html` element, I thought it would be worth mentioning the `:root` pseudo-class selector, which selects the root of the page (the `html` element in most scenarios) and could be more convenient in this scenario.

Usually, the `:root` selector is used to set CSS custom properties (variables) and font-sizes, but I'd say it would be reasonable to apply a `font-family` on it.

```css
:root {
  /* ...custom properties, font-size, etc... */
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know most people set the font family on the body element. But since there is no right or wrong (all elements are children of the html and body element), pick one and stick to it. This goes for all of the programming choices you make. This makes debugging your work a lot easier.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).