# :root, html, * selector. Any differences?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there any difference between those three CSS rules ?

```css
* {
  font-size: 24px
}
:root {
  font-size: 24px
}
html {
  font-size: 24px
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes there is a difference. Below some examples where the result isn't the same

Using `*`

```css
* {
  font-size: 24px
}

p {
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text <span>here</span></p>
</div>
```

Using `html` (or `:root`)

```css
html {
  font-size: 24px
}

p {
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text <span>here</span></p>
</div>
```

Applying `font-size` to all the elements is different from applying the `font-size` to the html element and having all the elements inherit the value.

In the first example, span will have a `font-size` equal to `24px` because it was selected by `*`. In the second example, span will inherit the computed value of `p` since no selector is targetting it.

---

between `html` and `:root` there is a specificity war where `:root` will be the winner:

```css
html {
  font-size: 999px;
}

:root {
  font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text <span>here</span></p>
</div>
```

```css
:root {
  font-size:24px;
}

html {
  font-size: 999px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text <span>here</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

All of them will affect your whole HTML. You can even use a forth option, that would be `html * { }`, that would work on all of your HTML.

Their meaning are:

- The `*` means that will select all elements - as per [CSS * Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp).
- The `:root` CSS pseudo-class matches the root element of a tree representing the document. In HTML, :root represents the `<html>` element and is identical to the selector `html`, except that its specificity is higher.

You can get more example and information on this post from the Community: [How to Apply global font to whole HTML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025756/how-to-apply-global-font-to-whole-html-document).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If we have something like this, with all of *, :root and html together as below

```css
* {
  background: green;
}

:root {
  background: yellow;
}

html {
  background: black;
}

h1 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading<span>Cow</span></h1>
```

The specificity is as below
:root(yellow) >html(black)>*(green)

Comment: Technically html does have higher specificity than * but in this example * is more specific to the particular element (<span>) being rendered.